# Best Product Listing Option for Concrete5

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, product, concrete5, listings

I'm going to be creating a Concrete5 website that will feature product listings. The listing system must offer all your typical ecommerce features, minus the ability to purchase items. It's strictly for browsing purposes only.

For example:
- Browse by category
- Search products
- Listings/results page with thumbnails and brief information (title, description, price in US/CAD, manufacturer, maker, etc.)
- Products single page (with detailed information, attributes and gallery/images)

All the things you'd expect to find in a listing system.

My issue is I can't find a specific add-on for something like product listings. This leaves me thinking that it may be best to use the e-commerce add on and do my best to hide anything related to the cart/payment process. That way it could just be used for everything else it offers.

What are your thoughts on this? Is there a better option?

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the page list block. It has everything you need except for searching. But, in essence, that's what your requirements call for -- listing of pages.

Create a page type for your "product". The "brief information" can be in the Content block, or you can set as attributes. You'll probably want to make some minor changes to the block's view (by creating a new template) that displays the image as you want, the proper attributes, etc. Something similar to http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/designers/styling-the-page-list-block/

There are several adanced page list blocks in the marketplace. You might want to start with those.

Comment: Like James S, I think you have to use attributes to do this. This concrete5 feature is great and handy.

Comment: Hmmmm interesting. I was thinking this originally, but hoping for more of a 'pre-built' add-on type of solution I suppose. I see the flexibility of this though, and it will offer most of the functionality I need. Attributes are definitely a powerful tool within Concrete5. Been using them a lot for powerful navigation in our last few projects.

Comment: Considering that you need to do something custom for your custom attributes regardless, page list is pretty much completely pre-built.

Answer (score 0):

Right creat Page type.
After creat Page attributes.
Add a block page_list create a template for it and filter by attributes.
You can even use ajax to filter.
http://www.weblicating.com/doku/doku.php?id=cheatsheet/#.UbR7P0BmiSp
U can find here about page_list or read documentation Concrete5.